# Google OAuth authentication calls redirect uri with # instead of?

Tags: node.js, express, google-api, gmail, google-oauth

I'm attempting to authenticate a server-side app in node.js using express.js as a middleware with the Google API to access the Gmail API and send emails from authenticated email accounts. I followed [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs?hl=en) at first and it works. The problem is that this doesn't work in offline mode which refreshes the access token without the need to ask the user for permission again. Then I followed [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server?hl=en) which uses the offline mode to refresh the tokens if needed. The problem here is that after the user authenticates the request in the browser and Google calls the provided redirect URI to the server the URI looks like the following:

`http://localhost:11000/oauth2callback#code=<code>&access_token=<access_token>&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3599&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send`

This obviously doesn't work because the browser doesn't forward the fragment part of the URI and I can't access the provided code and tokens. When I replace the # with ? the URI works as expected and I can access the query parameters on the server side.
The called oauth2 route looks like the following:

`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&response_type=code%20token&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fgmail.send&client_id=<client_id>&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A11000%2Foauth2callback`

This is the code to catch the request:

```js
const express = require('express'); 
const router = express.Router(); 

router.get('/oauth2callback', oauth2callback); 

async function oauth2callback(req, res) { 
// req.url is only /oauth2callback and req.query is empty 
}
```

I tried to change the parameters in the URI and used other example but to no avail.